# How to move selectInput box to go beside text?

Tags: shiny

I have selectInputs in my Shiny application but they leave a lot of blank gaps.

```
selectInput("vicNation", "Select victim nationality: ", 
                               choices = sort(unique(newngo$Victim.Nationality)), selected = NULL,
                               multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL)
```

When I run it i get:
[image]

Is it possible to move the selectInput to beside the text so there is less blank spaces

Comment: Put it in a `fluidRow(column(.......` so that you can control the width. See `?fluidRow`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to put the labels beside the `selectInput`?

Comment: Sorry if I haven't made it clear, I'd like to be move the drop down menu to go to the right of the text so it would be Select victim nationality: then drop down here instead of it starting below the text.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments:

```
  ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(column(3,
    "Select victim nationality: "),
    column(6,
    selectInput("vicNation", label = NULL, 
                choices = c('German','English','French'), selected = NULL,
                multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL)
    )
    )
  )
```